# unicode dictionary key issues with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary with unicode keys and I cannot seem to manipulate the elements inside

```
state_sentiment = {u'WA': [0.0], u'DC': [-2.0, 0.0], u'WI': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], u'WV': [0.0], u'FL': [2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],  u'OR': [6.0]}
for k,v in state_sentiment:
        max_score = -10.00
        happiest_state = ''
        current_score = float(sum(v))/len(v)
        if current_score > max_score:
            max_score = current_score
            happiest_state = state_sentiment[k]
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "happiest_state.py", line 61, in <module>
    processing()
  File "happiest_state.py", line 55, in processing
    readtweets(tweet_file, sent_dict)
  File "happiest_state.py", line 38, in readtweets
    current_score = float(sum(v))/len(v)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'
```

If I switch from `v` to `state_sentiment[k]`, still there is an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "happiest_state.py", line 59, in <module>
    processing()
  File "happiest_state.py", line 53, in processing
    readtweets(tweet_file, sent_dict)
  File "happiest_state.py", line 36, in readtweets
    current_score = float(sum(state_sentiment[k]))/len(state_sentiment[k])
KeyError: u'W'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over a dictionary just returns the keys.  You want:

```
for k, v in state_sentiment.iteritems():
```

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a dictionary, you actually iterate over its keys:

```
>>> for a in {'b': 2, 'c': 3}:
...     print a
...
c
b
```

Your code runs (but doesn't work properly) because `for k, v in state_sentiment` actually splits each key name up into individual characters:

```
>>> k, v = 'AB'
>>> k
'A'
>>> v
'B'
```

What you want to do instead is to iterate over the key-value *item pairs*:

```
for k, v in state_sentiment.items():
    ...
```

You can also just skip the loop and do this with `max()`:

```
def key_func(state):
    return sum(state[1]) / float(len(state[1]))

happiest_state = max(state_sentiment.items(), key=key_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in state_sentiment.items():
```

is what you want ... otherwise you are geting k="D",v="C"

```
print ["K:%s,V:%s"%(k,v) for k,v in state_sentiment]
```

since iterating over a dictionary only gives you the keys (which happen to be 2 letters long in this case (assigned to k,v respectively))